# Quels mots les mathématiciens français ont-ils le plus souvent utilisés pour les types de relations one-to-many o many-to-many ?

Tags: mathématiques, technologie

Aux États-Unis d'Amérique, les experts en bases de données informatiques utilisent parfois un langage connu sous le nom de **SQL**. (**Langage de requêtes structurés**).

Quels mots les mathématiciens français ont-ils le plus souvent utilisés de l'année 1950 jusqu'à l'an 2000 pour les types de relations suivantes ?

I used Google translate, but it is probably incorrect.

| relations un à un | one-to-one |
| --- | --- |
| relations plusieurs à un | many-to-one |
| relations un à plusieurs | one-to-many |
| relations plusieurs à plusieurs | many-to-many |

[image: ONE_TO one un-à-un]

[image: a slide from a slide shown presentation showing a many to one relationship. made using libre office impress, not Microsoft power point]

[image: a slide from a slide shown presentation showing a one to many relationship. made using libre office impress, not Microsoft power point]

[image: A PICTURE DE UNA RELATION DE plusieurs à plusieurs]

Comment: Je ne vois rien en dehors de la notation anglaise ou mathématiques (style "1:n"), à l'exception de la relation "one to many" parfois nommée "père-fils"

Comment: "PlusieurS" toujours avec un "s" :-)

Comment: Pourquoi les *mathématiciens* et pourquoi de 1950 à 2000 ?

Comment: en mathématique: *X à plusieurs* `relation` , *X à un* `fonction` (pour un à un, `injection` (sinon c'est N:1), pour plusieurs à un : `projection` (rarement utilisé)). le champ informatique des bases de données relationnelles n'est pas celui des mathématiques, on utilise donc un vocabulaire distinct.

Comment: @Archemar justement, la question devient complètement différente si on parle de théorie des ensembles. Or elle semble porter globalement sur l'informatique... hormis le mot "mathématicien", d'où mon interrogation.

Answer (score 2):

En base de données relationnelle, on utilise surtout les termes **1:1**, **1:N** et **N:M** (prononcés "*un un*", "*un N*" et "*N M*"), ainsi que les termes **[un à un](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_un-%C3%A0-un)**, **un à plusieurs**, **[plusieurs à un](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_plusieurs-%C3%A0-un)** et **plusieurs à plusieurs** (parfois avec des trait d'union : "*un-à-un*").

À part dans un contexte pédagogique (apprentissage et documentation), on utilise plutôt les premiers qui sont bien plus courts.

Comment: De mon côté j'ai déjà entendu parlé de relation N-N mais pas de relation N-M.

Comment: @XouDo Si on est pointilleux, N:N implique que le nombre est identique des deux côtés. Ce serait un cas particulier de "plusieurs à plusieurs" quasi inexistant en pratique. On entend de temps en temps N:N, mais c'est un abus de language. (D'ailleurs les termes ne sont pas spécifiques au français et existent de la même manière en anglais.)

Answer (score 0):

*Terminologie mathématique*

**for any x in the domain of the relation R, xRy and xRz forces y=z** : si cette condition est vraie on parle de *relation univoque* ou (synonyme) de *relation fonctionnelle*.

**one to one** : relation injective (Ce terme n'est pas utilisé, comme le plus souvent on ne parle de l'injectivité que lorsqu'on sait déjà qu'il s'agit d'une relation fonctionnelle, c'est à dire, d'une fonction.*), fonction injective

*Terminologie non utilisée en mathématiques*

Les "relations "one to many", "many to one", and "many to many" ne semblent pas être définies en mathématiques, c'est à dire qu'il n'existe pas de terme; si on les trouve, elles ne font pas l'objet d'études particulières dans les mathématiques traditionnelles.  On les trouve en informatique : [Relations : OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne et ManyToMany](http://www.middlewarefactory.com/avance-contraintes-et-relations-deux-entites-liees-a-travers-generic-system/) et elles ont alors les mêmes noms qu'en anglais.

Comment: On utilise injection, surjection et bijection dans les classes de maths françaises. Sinon, eg.: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_multivalu%C3%A9e.

Comment: Voir aussi: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_binaire. "Relation binaire" fait partie d'une présentation standard de la "théorie des ensembles" en classes de maths.

Comment: @Frank On ne s'occupe en fait que de relations binaires en algèbre. Il n'y a qu'en algèbre universelle que l'on parle de relations n-aires, et cela dans le but de généraliser.

Comment: Oui, oui. Je sais bien, mais comme la question est à mi-chemin entre les maths et l'informatique, je voulais juste apporter des pointeurs pour le côté maths. Du côté informatique, je ne connais pas de terminologie spécifiquement française. Je ne crois pas qu'on utilise injection, surjection, bijection en informatique quotidienne, certainement pas dans le contexte de SQL.

Comment: @Frank Je ne connais pas l'informatique, mais j'ai l'impression qu'on y utilise des concepts tirés des mathématiques sans introduire le formalisme mathématique, ou même en le rendant insignifiant. Par exemple dans la référence que je fournis ci-dessus les relations sont introduites sans la moindre référence aux ensembles, ce qui est impensable selon le point de vue des mathématiciens.

Comment: Aussi, tous les exemples SQL plus haut sont des exemples de relations binaires, pas n-aires, car il y a seulement deux ensembles en jeu. Mais effectivement, je ne crois pas qu'il y ait une terminologie spécifique pour chaque de type relation binaire présenté plus haut.

Comment: Je connais très bien l'informatique. Dans le contexte SQL, je ne pense pas que beaucoup de maths soient requis ou utilisés. Il y a plus de maths dans certains sous-domaines de l'informatique, mais pas trop pour une utilisation quotidienne ("programmeur/développeur") de SQL.

Comment: What is the reason for this negative vote? Is it too difficult to explain in two or three words where the would-be error is found?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a one-to-one relation is generally a *bijective function* and not just an *injective function*. But the downvote could easily have been for other reasons.

Comment: @PeterShor It wasn't so in the US 40 years ago, and it is not so in France today; from a 2003 algebra course, Dunod, Lelong-Ferrand and Arnaudiès : "(*f* bijective) <=> (*f* injective) & *f* surjective)".  The injectivity is the same condition as one-to-oneness. It is still so world-wide, I believe; here is Wikipedia's notes on injectivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function — maybe you are thinking about "one-to-one correspondence". This should be true since any function has to be a relation. That is why I mention that "relation injective", although correct, is not used. (1/2)

Comment: @PeterShor Here is what I get from *Atlas des mathématiques* Fritz Reinhrdt et Heinrich Soeder : "propiétés des relations binaires — R injective <=> (∀x,z,y (xRy & zRy ==> x=z))". (2/2)

Comment: I think it depends on what field the terminology relates to. Consider this [website](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fone-to-one-relationships.html%23~text%3DIn%2520a%2520one-to-one%2Cassigned%2520to%2520only%2520one%2520person.) about databases: "In a one-to-one relationship, one record in a table is associated with one and only one record in another table." Look at the figure in the OP; it's clearly a bijection, and not just an injection.

Comment: @PeterShor In fact, as far as this particular case is concerned, they do not make necessary that all elements in the second list should have an inverse image : "One-to-one relationship : A correspondence between data in database tables in which one record in the first table is related to one record in another table.". Their language is not precise and leads to confusion in the end. The term "correspondence" is missing from their lexicon. Taken as in French mathematics, a correspondence is nothing more than a subset from a cartesian product (C=AXB), (1/2)

Comment: what in Anglo-Saxon maths is called a relation (I see no difference with "relationship"). For instance, C={(a,x),(a,y),…(b,x),(b,y),…(c,x),…(d,x),(d,y),(d,z),(d,w)}; all subsets of C are *relations* between A (={a,b,c,d} and B (={x,y,z,w}). As I read your "about", I thought it might be useless to recall such things, but probably the foundations of maths are of no use in your work. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Je répondrai ici en tant qu'informaticien.
En cours de [Merise][1], on parlait de relation (par abus de langage, cardinalité) « 1, 1 », « 1 n » ou « n n ». Je comprends le [commentaire de Teleporting Goat](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/quels-mots-les-math%C3%A9maticiens-fran%C3%A7ais-ont-ils-le-plus-souvent-utilis%C3%A9s-pour-les#comment110633_52819), mais je n'ai jamais utilisé « n m » qu'à un partiel, plus jamais après. De toute ma vie !
Dans le monde professionnel ou en cours d'UML, on utilise « one to one », « one to many », « many to one » et « many to many ». La francisation serait ici curieuse, voire attirerait les moqueries.

De manière générale, en informatique, on utilisera l'expression anglaise - sans oublier bien sûr de rajouter un accent français bien marqué : « sraid » pour “thread”, ou « line keudine » pour “LinkedIn”.

[1]: je fais de l'informatique de gestion depuis une vingtaine d'années. J'ai été étudiant à Aix peu après Tardieu, Espinasse et Le Moigne.

Comment: Bienvenue Olivier.  Est-ce qu'il y a une source qui n'est pas le commentaire pour la question des maths  ?